# Combobox с подсказкой вариантов в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Есть код, который выполняет поиск в списке по нажатию кнопки выпадающего списка.

Не могу понять, как мне обрабатывать это в прямом эфире, чтобы при вводе слов сразу показывались подходящие значения. 
(без *ООП*, т.к. привязать *ООП* к своей утилите я не смогу). 
Спасибо

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

lst = ['C', 'C++', 'Java',
   'Python', 'Perl',
   'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS']


def check_input(event):
    value = event.widget.get()

    if value == '':
        combo_box['values'] = lst
    else:
        data = []
        for item in lst:
            if value.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)

        combo_box['values'] = data


root = Tk()

# creating Combobox
combo_box = ttk.Combobox(root)
combo_box['values'] = lst
combo_box.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_input)
combo_box.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: На самом деле у вас и так фильтрует в реальном времени, просто результат можно увидеть только открыв выпадающий список. Просто скорее всего не получится. Я нашел [такой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59913585/4752653), но после нажатия любой клавиши выпадающий список забирает фокус и не дает дальше печатать, в итоге в таком решении нет никакого смысла. Я когда-то делал просто поле Entry и под ним Listbox, в котором отображался отфильтрованный список. Как вариант можно в отдельном всплывающем окне отображать Listbox, но это довольно сложное решение.

Comment: У меня есть решение через entry+lisbox см. [анимацию](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAy5t.gif), без скрытия списка. Если такой вариант подойдет, могу выложить ответом.

Comment: @insolor, было бы неплохо. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteCombobox # pip install ttkwidgets


lst = [
    'C', 'C++', 'Java',
    'Python', 'Perl',
    'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS'
]

root = Tk()

# creating Combobox
combo_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=30, completevalues=lst)

combo_box.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Интересно, правда я думал в выпадающем списке будут отображаться варианты, а он в текстовом поле автодополнение показывает.

Comment: @S.Nick Почему оно на каждое новую нажатую клавишу ищет новое слово? как пофиксить чтобы оно показывало результат нескольких букв? например в списке из 1000+ параметров найти нужный этим способом не получается, т.к. на эту букву начинается много слов. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Пример с `Entry` + `Listbox` (без скрытия списка):

```
from tkinter import *

lst = [
    'C', 'C++', 'Java',
    'Python', 'Perl',
    'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS'
]


def check_input(_event=None):
    value = entry.get().lower()

    if value == '':
        listbox_values.set(lst)
    else:
        data = []
        for item in lst:
            if value.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)

        listbox_values.set(data)


root = Tk()

entry_text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_input)
entry.pack()


def on_change_selection(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        data = event.widget.get(index)
        entry_text.set(data)
        check_input()


listbox_values = Variable()
listbox = Listbox(root, listvariable=listbox_values)
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_change_selection)
listbox.pack()
listbox_values.set(lst)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Спасибо, думал о чем-то похожем.
.
Браво!
.
А есть у тебя твой  блог или какой курс по Tk/ttk?
платный например?

.
А то всё, что я нашел - как-то бедненько

Comment: А где можно почитать про Variable() ?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, нет, блога/курса нет. Все что есть - ответы на stackoverflow. Про Variable не помню где нашел, но тут просто этот объект хранит список значений для Listbox, по аналогии например со StringVar для текстового поля.