# Фильтрующийся выпадающий список по мере ввода в поле в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

По материалам [вопроса о списке с фильтрующимися ответами по мере ввода в поле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1322933/combobox-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-tkinter) попробовал написать аналогичный код с всплывающим окном. Окно всплывает, да в нем-то пусто.
Подскажете?

Здесь задумівалось следующее. Поле для ввода снабжено двумя обработчиками событий:

1. отслеживание ввода в поле - для передачи введенных символов в окно фильтрации выпадающего списка
2. собственно выпадающий список, в котором должны быть видны строки, начинающиеся с символов введенной строки.
   Ну обычный выбор города из списка.

Проще я реализовать это не смог, так как его величество полноценный Tk в Python не обладает примерами такого типа. Тьюторы все какие то детские даже [здесь](http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html), у авторов библиотеки ...
Конкретно здесь - выбор языка программирования из списка с позиционированием
в списке по частичному вводу. Повторюсь, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1322933/combobox-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-tkinter) все работает, я попытался добавить отдельное окно, появляющееся по нажатию правой мышки.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def on_change_selection(event):
    # перенос выбранного из списка значения в окно ввода
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        data = event.widget.get(index)
        entry_text.set(data)
        filter_listbox(event)



def create_listbox(event):
    # создание выпадающего окна со списком языков. Может нужен OnTop() ?
    global city_start_values_list
    global city_listbox, listbox_values
    print("box creating")

    list_root = tk.Tk()
    listbox_values = tk.Variable(master=list_root)  # list_root
    city_listbox = tk.Listbox(list_root, listvariable=listbox_values)
    city_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_change_selection)

    city_listbox.pack()
    list_root.mainloop()


def filter_listbox(event):
    global city_start_values_list
    global city_listbox, listbox_values

    entered_text = ent_lookup.get().lower()
    if not listbox_values:
        return
    if entered_text == '':
        listbox_values.set(city_start_values_list)
        # city_listbox["values"] = city_start_values_list
    else:
        # фильтруем значения, начинающиеся с подстроки
        values = [el for el in city_start_values_list if el.startswith(entered_text)]
        # city_listbox["values"] = values
        listbox_values.set(values)

    print(ent_lookup.get())


# основная программа - задание поля ввода с описанием. binding обработчиков
city_listbox, listbox_values = None, None

city_start_values_list = [
    'C', 'C++', 'Java',
    'Python', 'Perl',
    'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS'
]


root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(170, 100)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="2 5 2 2")
mainframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

lbl_lookup = ttk.Label(mainframe, text='real')
lbl_lookup.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

entry_text = tk.StringVar(root)
ent_lookup = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30, textvariable=entry_text)
ent_lookup.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

ent_lookup.bind('<Button-3>', create_listbox)
ent_lookup.bind('<KeyRelease>', filter_listbox)  # '<Key>'

root.mainloop()
```

Вот:
[image: пустое окно по правой мышке]

Да и вообще - где почитать про tk.Variable() и параметры `textvariable` для `Entry` и `listvariable`   для `Listbox` ?  В интернете про них тишина...

Comment: [`Variable`](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Variable-class.html) - это базовый класс для `BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`, `IntVar` и `StringVar`. Ну, а про всякие параметры (типа `listvariable`) можно прочитать в [первоисточнике](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/listbox.html#M8) Tcl/Tk (т.к. tkinter это надстройка над Tk). В Tcl там у listbox'а это просто переменная содержащая список строк. Список в Tcl - это в простом случае строка (элементы разделённые пробелами). Если элементы содержат пробелы, то по-сложнее, но всё равно строка. Как это транслируется в Питон - понятия не имею.

Comment: Вот ещё по этому вопросу - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383170/modify-listbox-entries-via-listvariable-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил, дополнил, заработало )

[image: пример выпадающего меню, отфильтрованного по первой букве ввода]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def on_change_selection(event):
    # перенос выбранного из списка значения в окно ввода
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    global var_entry_text
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        data = event.widget.get(index)
        var_entry_text.set(data)
        filter_listbox(event)


def create_listbox(event):
    # создание выпадающего окна со списком языков. Может нужен OnTop() ?
    global city_start_values_list
    global city_listbox, listbox_values
    print("box creating")

    list_root = tk.Tk()
    listbox_values = tk.Variable(master=list_root)  # list_root
    listbox_values.set(city_start_values_list)
    city_listbox = tk.Listbox(list_root, listvariable=listbox_values)
    city_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_change_selection)

    if var_entry_text.get() != '':
        filter_listbox(event)

    city_listbox.pack()
    list_root.mainloop()


def filter_listbox(event):
    global city_start_values_list
    global city_listbox, listbox_values

    entered_text = ent_lookup.get().lower()
    z = str(entered_text)
    if not city_listbox:  # выпадающий список еще не создан
        create_listbox(event)

    if not listbox_values:
        return
    if entered_text == '':
        listbox_values.set(city_start_values_list)
        # city_listbox["values"] = city_start_values_list
    else:
        # фильтруем значения, начинающиеся с подстроки
        values = [el for el in city_start_values_list if el.lower().startswith(entered_text)]
        # city_listbox["values"] = values
        listbox_values.set(values)

    print(ent_lookup.get())


# основная программа - задание поля ввода с описанием. binding обработчиков
city_listbox, listbox_values = None, None

city_start_values_list = [
    'C', 'C++', 'Java',
    'Python', 'Perl',
    'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS'
]


root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(170, 100)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="2 5 2 2")
mainframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

lbl_lookup = ttk.Label(mainframe, text='real')
lbl_lookup.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

var_entry_text = tk.StringVar(root)
var_entry_text.set('')
ent_lookup = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=30, textvariable=var_entry_text)
ent_lookup.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

ent_lookup.bind('<Button-3>', create_listbox)
ent_lookup.bind('<KeyRelease>', filter_listbox)  # '<Key>'

root.mainloop()
```