# Как отключить сворачивание ComboBox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

При вводе символов в поле происходит фильтрация списка. Но сам ComboBox при этом закрывается. Приходится его открывать по новой и смотреть результат. Как сделать чтобы ComboBox не закрывался?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

lst = ['C', 'C++', 'Java',
    'Python', 'Perl',
    'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS']

def check_input(self, *args):
    value = combobox1_check_list.get().lower()

    if value == '':
        combobox1_check_list['values'] = lst
    else:
        data = []
        for item in lst:
            if value.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)

        combobox1_check_list['values'] = data

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x450")
lll = StringVar()
lll.trace('w',check_input)
combobox1_check_list = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable = lll)
combobox1_check_list.place(x=90, y=10)
combobox1_check_list['values'] = lst
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Есть большая вероятность, что средствами tkinter это сделать не получится. Можно как-то эмулировать комбобокс, создавать окошко без рамки, в нем выводить список. Либо сделать текстовое поле + список под ним (не всплывающий, просто список в окне).

Comment: варианты с использованием listbox и entry я видел, но тут как бы логично в таком виджете эта функция.

Comment: Ну я бы не сказал, что прямо логично. Фильтрация списка - эта довольно специфический способ использования комбобокса. Это уже не комбобокс фактически будет, а что-то типа строки поиска. Комбобокс изначально предназначен просто для выбора из выпадающего списка.

Comment: "варианты с использованием listbox и entry я видел" - судя по коду в вопросе, вы скорее всего видели [мой вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1323054/1365). В целом, у вас код в вопросе совпадает с кодом в том вопросе, см. [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1322933/combobox-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-tkinter/1323054#comment2337552_1322933) - с тех пор особо ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Можно сделать, чтоб ComboBox сам открывался, используя виртуальное событие `combobox1_check_list.event_generate('<Down>')`  в конце функции `check_input`.

Comment: уже вариант, хоть и дает вводить по 1 символу